# Remove elements in elements of alist Python

Tags: python, json, list

I have a list that looks like that:

```
[{'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'error': True,
  'reason': 'Reserved IP Address',
  'reserved': True,
  'version': 'IPv4'},
 {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'error': True,
  'reason': 'Reserved IP Address',
  'reserved': True,
  'version': 'IPv4'},
 {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'version': 'IPv4',
  'city': 'Munich',
  'region': 'Bavaria',
  'country': 'DE',
  'country_name': 'Germany',
  'country_code': 'DE',
  'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
  'country_capital': 'Berlin'},
 {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'version': 'IPv4',
  'city': 'Düsseldorf',
  'region': 'North Rhine-Westphalia',
  'country': 'DE',
  'country_name': 'Germany',
  'country_code': 'DE',
  'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
  'country_capital': 'Berlin'}]
```

What I need is a way to remove that elements than have an "error" or "reason : 'Reserved IP Address'" element inside and get only the elements that have complete data. Like this:

```
#Removing unnecesary elements
[{'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'version': 'IPv4',
  'city': 'Munich',
  'region': 'Bavaria',
  'country': 'DE',
  'country_name': 'Germany',
  'country_code': 'DE',
  'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
  'country_capital': 'Berlin'},
 {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
  'version': 'IPv4',
  'city': 'Düsseldorf',
  'region': 'North Rhine-Westphalia',
  'country': 'DE',
  'country_name': 'Germany',
  'country_code': 'DE',
  'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
  'country_capital': 'Berlin'}]
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with list comprehension:

```
>>> [d for d in mylist if not d.get("error") and d.get("reason")!="Reserved IP Address"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach using the filter method, might be more flexible for more complex conditions

```
list_of_dict = [{'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
                 'error': True,
                 'reason': 'Reserved IP Address',
                 'reserved': True,
                 'version': 'IPv4'},
                {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
                 'error': True,
                 'reason': 'Reserved IP Address',
                 'reserved': True,
                 'version': 'IPv4'},
                {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
                 'version': 'IPv4',
                 'city': 'Munich',
                 'region': 'Bavaria',
                 'country': 'DE',
                 'country_name': 'Germany',
                 'country_code': 'DE',
                 'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
                 'country_capital': 'Berlin'},
                {'ip': 'x.x.x.x',
                 'version': 'IPv4',
                 'city': 'Düsseldorf',
                 'region': 'North Rhine-Westphalia',
                 'country': 'DE',
                 'country_name': 'Germany',
                 'country_code': 'DE',
                 'country_code_iso3': 'DEU',
                 'country_capital': 'Berlin'}]


def contains_error(dictionary):
    return ('error' or 'reason') not in dictionary


result = list(filter(contains_error, list_of_dict))
print(result)
```